# __str__ and pretty-printing (sub)dictionaries

Tags: python, pprint

I have an object that consists primarily of a very large nested dictionary:

```
class my_object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.the_dict = {}  # Big, nested dictionary
```

I've modified __ str__ to pretty-print the top-level dictionary by simply "printing" the object:

```
    def __str__(self):
        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
        return pp.pformat(self.the_dict)
```

My goal here was to make the user's life a bit easier when he/she peruses the object with IPython:

```
print(the_object)  # Pretty-prints entire dict
```

This works to show the user the entire dictionary, but I would like to expand this functionality to sub-portions of the dictionary as well, allowing the user to get pretty-printed output from commands such as:

```
print(the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3'])
```

(would pretty-print only the 'level3' sub-dict)

Is there a straight-forward way to use __ str__ (or similar) to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide a custom displayhook that prints builtin dictionaries and other objects you choose according to your taste at an interactive prompt:

```
>>> import sys
>>> oldhook = sys.displayhook
>>> sys.displayhook = your_module.DisplayHook(oldhook)
```

It doesn't change `print obj` behavior.

The idea is that your users can choose whether they'd like to use your custom formatting for `dict`s or not.

Comment: Ooooh!  Shiny!  Not familiar with this functionality.  Will give this a spin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When a user says

```
print(the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3'])
```

Python evaluates `the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3']` and (let's say) finds it is a dict, and passes that on to `print`.

Since `the_object.the_dict` is a dict, the rest is out of `the_object`'s control. As you burrow down through `level1`, `level2`, and `level3`, only the type of object returned by `the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3']` is going to affect how `print` behaves. `the_object`'s `__str__` method is not going to affect anything beyond `the_object` itself.

Moreover, when printing nested objects, `pprint.pformat` uses the `repr` of the object, not `str` of the object.

So to get the behave we want, we need `the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3']` to evaluate to something like a dict but with a different `__repr__`...

---

You could make a dict-like object (e.g. `Turtle`) and use `Turtles` all the way down:

```
import collections
import pprint

class Turtle(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self._data=dict(*args,**kwargs)
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self._data[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._data[key]=value
    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._data[key]
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._data)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._data)
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return x in self._data
    def __repr__(self):
        return pprint.pformat(self._data)

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.the_dict=Turtle()
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.the_dict)

the_object=MyObject()
the_object.the_dict['level1']=Turtle()
the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']=Turtle()
the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3']=Turtle({i:i for i in range(20)})
print(the_object)
print(the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3'])
```

To use this, you must replace all dicts in your nested dict structure with `Turtle`s.

But really (as you can tell from my fanciful naming), I don't really expect you to use `Turtle`s. Dicts are such nice, optimized builtins, I would not want to add this intermediate object just to effect pretty printing.

If instead you can convince your users to type

```
from pprint import pprint
```

then they can just use

```
pprint(the_object.the_dict['level1']['level2']['level3'])
```

to get pretty printing.

Comment: Good logic.  I came to the same conclusion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the underlying dictionaries to "pretty printing dictionaries" ... perhaps something like this will do:

```
class my_object( object ):
  _pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

  class PP_dict( dict ):
      def __setitem__( self, key, value ):
          if isinstance( value, dict ): value = PP_dict( value )
          super( my_object.PP_dict, self ).__setitem__( key, value )

      def __str__( self ):
          return my_object.pp( self )

  @property
  def the_dict( self ):
      return self.__dict__[ 'the_dict' ]

  @the_dict.setter
  def the_dict( self, value ):
      self.__dict__[ 'the_dict' ] = my_object.PP_dict( value )
```

The property is only because I don't know how you set/manipulate "the_dict".

This approach is limited -- for instance if you put dict-derivatives that are not dicts in the_dict, they will be replaced by PP_dict. Also, if you have other reference to these subdicts, they will no longer be pointing to the same objects.

Another approach would be to put a `__getitem__` in my_object directly, that returns a proxy wrapper for the dictionary that pretty prints the current object in `__str__`, overrides `__getitem__` to return proxies for subobjects, and otherwise forwards all acccess/manipulation to the wrapped class.